# SQL for 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these 2 tables:

```
Table A

Country    State
-----------------
 US         OH
 US         FL
 US         WA


Table B

State    LastVisitDate   City
----------------------------------
 OH        15/10/2019    Bedford
 FL        10/12/2019    Bell
 WA        20/09/2019    Perth
```

Table A can be linked with table B by field "State".

What would be the query to get the latest (last visit date) in country=US, doesn't matter which state, e.g.:

### US,10-12-2019,FL,Bell

I tried inner join but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always try to explain your question with sample data and query you tried for.

Here is query with some sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
    COUNTRY VARCHAR(10),
    State VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO A VALUES('US','OH'),
('US','FL'),
('AU','WA');

CREATE TABLE B
(
    State VARCHAR(10),
    LastVisitDate DATE,
    City VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO B VALUES
('OH','2019-10-15','Bedford'),
('FL','2019-12-10','Bell'),
('WA','2019-09-20','Perth');
```

**Expected Result**:

```
US,10-12-2019,FL,Bell
```

Query:

```
SELECT a.COUNTRY,b.LastVisitDate,b.State,b.City
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON a.State = b.State 
WHERE a.COUNTRY = 'US'
ORDER BY b.LastVisitDate DESC
Limit 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/2d8d4/1)

Comment: i think this answer was help full please try like this

Answer (score 0):

> Before you try below code you must be reformat **last visited date** table structure like **YYYY/MM/DD** in SQL Table and you **must replace actual tables name and columns name in below query**.

```
SELECT  MAX(table_b.last_visited_date) AS last_visited_date
FROM table_a
INNER JOIN table_b
ON table_a.state = table_b.state WHERE table_a.country = 'US' Limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT top 1(country,
             last_visit_date)
FROM A
JOIN B ON A.State = B.State
WHERE A.Country ="Country Name"
ORDER BY B.Last_visit_Date DESC
```

Comment: Please, read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) topic. Since your answer covers the question, it is worth to explain the details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

Note: As Tanmay said, you need to reformat your date values to get the correct output.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=716ee2e9e7a1a894a3d6066739bcb64f)

```
SELECT N.country, 
N.mx_date LastVisitDate,
B.City,
B.State
FROM
(
    SELECT Country,MAX(LastVisitDate) mx_date
    FROM Table_A A
    INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.State = B.State
    GROUP BY Country
 )N  
 INNER JOIN Table_A A ON A.Country = N.Country
 INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.State = B.State
 WHERE N.mx_date = B.LastVisitDate
```